# PostgreSQL phppgadmin not having Trigger functions in Cpanel

Tags: php, postgresql, cpanel

I am new to **PostgreSQL** and My project is based on php **yii2** framework. All tables working fine in live. i created a trigger function on my local server and its working good in local. But in Cpanel I didn't have Trigger function in Phppgadmin. can any one help me to create trigger function on live.

**phppgadminimage**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute your trigger DDL in SQL editor and then check the trigger in particular table.

Navigation :  your_schema >> Tables >> Table.

That will show the trigger in triggers tab.